# MySql Insert multiple and Ignore duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have this MySQL INSERT query that adds a Product to multiple categories:

```
INSERT INTO _categories_products (product_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 14), (1, 8), (1, 1), (1, 22);
```

This works great, however, if I add the same product to another subcategory from the same parent, it will create duplicate records for the parent categories:

```
INSERT INTO _categories_products (product_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 14), (1, 8), (1, 1), (1, 23);
```

[image]

Question: What would be the appropriate MySQL query that Ignores the insertion of duplicate records? In other words, the second query should INSERT only one record: `1, 23`.

I tried also INSERT IGNORE INTO but nothing changed.

Thank You!

---

Comment: is `(product_id, category_id)` a unique key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, you want to create a unique constraint on categories/product tuples to avoid duplicates:

```
alter table _categories_products  
    add constraint _categories_products _bk 
    unique (product_id, category_id);
```

From that point on, an attempt to insert duplicates in the table would, by default, raise an error. You can trap and manage that error with [MySQL `on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
insert into _categories_products (product_id, category_id) 
values (1, 14), (1, 8), (1, 1), (1, 23)
on duplicate key update product_id = values(product_id)
```

In the case of duplicate, the above query performs a dumb update on `product_id`, which actually turns the insert to a no-op.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` should also work in the scenario you suggest.